# Telerik upload manager - Folder creates and deletes but refresh images stays

Tags: c#, javascript, upload, telerik

Having problems with the documentmanager upload trying to upload PDF's.

The problem happens when creating or deleting folders. The get create/deleted in the correct location but the refresh/processing image stays, crashing the tool from navigating the folder structure. See screen shot:

[image]

There is a Javascript error :

```
this._clientParameters.get_value is not a function
```

CODE

```
FileManagerDialogParameters documentManagerParameters = new FileManagerDialogParameters();
        documentManagerParameters.ViewPaths = new string[] { uploadPath };
        documentManagerParameters.UploadPaths = new string[] { uploadPath };
        documentManagerParameters.DeletePaths = new string[] { uploadPath };
        documentManagerParameters.SearchPatterns = pattern;
        documentManagerParameters.MaxUploadFileSize = maxFileSize;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dialog))
        {
            // use a default
            dialog = "~/modules/uploadcentre/dialogs/default/";
        }

        documentManagerParameters["ExternalDialogsPath"] = dialog;

        DialogDefinition documentManager = new DialogDefinition(typeof(DocumentManagerDialog), documentManagerParameters)
        {
            ClientCallbackFunction = "DocumentManagerFunction",
            Width = Unit.Pixel(694),
            Height = Unit.Pixel(440)
        };

        DialogOpener1.DialogDefinitions.Add("DocumentManager", documentManager);
```

Telerik.web.ui version 2011.1.519.40

Thanks in advance

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/document-manage-refreshing-image-stays-on.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please, see the following forum thread which discusses the same JS error:
DocumentManager open with DialogOpener javascript error - http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/documentmanager-open-with-dialogopener-javascript-error.aspx

If you need further help, please open a support ticket from www.telerik.com and send a sample fully working project that demonstrates the problem.

Best regards,
Rumen